# Unable to set waitForAnimate to true for slick.js carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have has a very strange problem, where, I can set `waitForAnimate` to `false`, but not to `true`... Here is an example of what I mean:

```js
$(".carousel").slick({
  waitForAnimate: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  dots: true,
  appendArrows: $(".carousel-arrows"),
  nextArrow: "<button>Next</button>",
  prevArrow: "<button>Previous</button>"
});

$(".set-waitforanimate-false").click(function() {
  $(".carousel").slick("slickSetOption", "waitForAnimate", "false")
});
$(".set-waitforanimate-true").click(function() {
  $(".carousel").slick("slickSetOption", "waitForAnimate", "true")
});
```

```css
.carousel-img img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-HGOnQO9+SP1V92SrtZfjqxxtLmVzqZpjFFekvzZVWoiASSQgSr4cw9Kqd2+l8Llp4Gm0G8GIFJ4ddwZilcdb8A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">

<div class="carousel-arrows"></div>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/201"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/202"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/203"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/204"></div>
</div>

<button class="set-waitforanimate-false" type="button">Set waitForAnimate to false</button>
<button class="set-waitforanimate-true" type="button">Set waitForAnimate to true</button>
```

For whatever reason, when using `$().slick('slickSetOption', ...)` to set `waitForAnimate` to `false`, it **works**, but when using it to set `waitForAnimate` to `true`, it **doesn't** (I have also tried this with setting `refresh` to `true` and `false`).
Why is this the case, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to store the caraousel to a variable first to be able to change the existing attributes. And you need to pass a boolean instead of a string to change the atrribute.

```js
var slider = $(".carousel").slick({
  waitForAnimate: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  dots: true,
  appendArrows: $(".carousel-arrows"),
  nextArrow: "<button>Next</button>",
  prevArrow: "<button>Previous</button>"
});

$(".set-waitforanimate-false").click(function() {
  slider.slick("slickSetOption", "waitForAnimate", false);
});
$(".set-waitforanimate-true").click(function() {
  slider.slick("slickSetOption", "waitForAnimate", true);
});
```

```css
.carousel-img img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-HGOnQO9+SP1V92SrtZfjqxxtLmVzqZpjFFekvzZVWoiASSQgSr4cw9Kqd2+l8Llp4Gm0G8GIFJ4ddwZilcdb8A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">

<div class="carousel-arrows"></div>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/201"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/202"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/203"></div>
  <div class="carousel-img"><img src="https://picsum.photos/204"></div>
</div>

<button class="set-waitforanimate-false" type="button">Set waitForAnimate to false</button>
<button class="set-waitforanimate-true" type="button">Set waitForAnimate to true</button>
```